# replace dash by space in pytest's report

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm on my way to simplify a set of tests by `pytest` by stacking parameters

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_a", ["-r", "-s"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_b", ["--alpha", "--beta", "--gamma"])
def test_foo(option_a, option_b):
    assert option_a in ["-r", "-s"]
```

As anticipated, the above MWE performs an exhaustive permutation:

```
======================================= test session starts =======================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/guest/Desktop/project, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 6 items                                                                                 

test_ping.py::test_foo[--alpha--r] PASSED                                                   [ 16%]
test_ping.py::test_foo[--alpha--s] PASSED                                                   [ 33%]
test_ping.py::test_foo[--beta--r] PASSED                                                    [ 50%]
test_ping.py::test_foo[--beta--s] PASSED                                                    [ 66%]
test_ping.py::test_foo[--gamma--r] PASSED                                                   [ 83%]
test_ping.py::test_foo[--gamma--s] PASSED                                                   [100%]

======================================== 6 passed in 0.02s ========================================
```

What bothers me a bit is the additional dash trailing the first parameter (`--alpha`, `--beta`, `--gamma`).  Someone not familiar enough with `pytest` may assume the second parameter tested would be `--r` (instead of `-r`), or `--s` (instead of `-s`).

Is there a practical approach to substitute this separator by a blank space?  Since this is just an issue how output to the CLI is formatted, I would like to refrain to define multiple fixtures for each test function.

Comment: As a suggestion, you could use `ids`. `@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_a", ["-r", "-s"], ids=["\"-r\"", "\"-s\""])`. It will not remove hyphen between parameters but could decrease confusion.

Comment: @AndreiZhidelev I believe that is an answer, and perhaps the only possible answer :) Feel free to post it. Would upvote.

Comment: @AndreiZhidelev Given this piece of information, and knowing `pytest` is going use the parameter with the higher number of levels as outer loop (here: `option_b`), the one with less levels as the inner one (here: `option_a`), one may edit your suggest further into `@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_a", ["-r", "-s"], ids=[" -r", " -s"])` (with leading spaces) and `@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_b", ["--alpha", "--beta", "--gamma"], ids=["--alpha ", "--beta ", "--gamma "])` (trailing spaces).  Me to, I were happy to upvote your comment *as an answer*.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano, thank you, I have updated and posted an answer :-)

Comment: @Buttonwood, thank you, I have updated and posted an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize our comments, it's possible to use [ids](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html?highlight=ids#different-options-for-test-ids) and keep in mind test ordering. `pytest` is going to use the parameter with the higher number of levels as an outer loop (here: `option_b`), the one with fewer levels as the inner one (here: `option_a`). Also, I have added the `custom_format` function as an example of an approach how to custom a view of a parameter.

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_a", ["-r", "-s"], ids=[" -r", " -s"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_b", ["--alpha", "--beta", "--gamma"], ids=["--alpha ", "--beta ", "--gamma "])
def test_foo(option_a, option_b):
    assert option_a in ["-r", "-s"]

def custom_format(val):
    return f" {val} "

@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_a", ["-r", "-s"], ids=custom_format)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("option_b", ["--alpha", "--beta", "--gamma"], ids=custom_format)
def test_foo_1(option_a, option_b):
    assert option_a in ["-r", "-s"]
```

It will not remove hyphens between parameters but could decrease confusion.

```
collected 12 items

test_.py::test_foo[--alpha - -r] PASSED                                                                                                              [  8%]
test_.py::test_foo[--alpha - -s] PASSED                                                                                                              [ 16%]
test_.py::test_foo[--beta - -r] PASSED                                                                                                               [ 25%]
test_.py::test_foo[--beta - -s] PASSED                                                                                                               [ 33%]
test_.py::test_foo[--gamma - -r] PASSED                                                                                                              [ 41%]
test_.py::test_foo[--gamma - -s] PASSED                                                                                                              [ 50%]
test_.py::test_foo_1[ --alpha - -r ] PASSED                                                                                                          [ 58%]
test_.py::test_foo_1[ --alpha - -s ] PASSED                                                                                                          [ 66%]
test_.py::test_foo_1[ --beta - -r ] PASSED                                                                                                           [ 75%]
test_.py::test_foo_1[ --beta - -s ] PASSED                                                                                                           [ 83%]
test_.py::test_foo_1[ --gamma - -r ] PASSED                                                                                                          [ 91%]
test_.py::test_foo_1[ --gamma - -s ] PASSED                                                                                                          [100%]
```